# ExpandableListView onChildClickListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, expandablelistadapter

I am a new bee to android.

I am working with ExpandableListViewAdapter and facing a problem.

The onChildClickListener is not working when I click on the edit text box.

My question is will it work on edit text box or not.

I am implementing the BaseExpandableListAdapter.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class TryExpandableListViewActivity extends Activity implements     OnChildClickListener {

LinearLayout llayout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    llayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llayout);

    ExpandableListView list = new ExpandableListView(this);
    list.setGroupIndicator(null);
    list.setChildIndicator(null);
    String[] titles = {"A","B","C"};
    String[] fruits = {"a1","a2"};
    String[] veggies = {"b1","b2","b3"};
    String[] meats = {"c1","c2"};
    String[][] contents = {fruits,veggies,meats};
    SimplerExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimplerExpandableListAdapter(this,titles, contents);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    llayout.addView(list);

    list.setOnChildClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    Log.i("Test","-------------------------------------------");
    return false;
}
```

}

```
class SimplerExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private String[][] mContents;
private String[] mTitles;

public SimplerExpandableListAdapter(Context context, String[] titles, String[][] contents) {
    super();
    if(titles.length != contents.length) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Titles and Contents must be the same size.");
    }
    mContext = context;
    mContents = contents;
    mTitles = titles;

  }

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mContents[groupPosition][childPosition];
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

        EditText row = (EditText)convertView;
        if(row == null) {
          row = new EditText(mContext);
        }
        row.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        row.setText(mContents[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        return row;

}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return mContents[groupPosition].length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mContents[groupPosition];
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mContents.length;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView row = (TextView)convertView;
    if(row == null) {
      row = new TextView(mContext);
    }
    row.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    row.setText(mTitles[groupPosition]);
    return row;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: i have edit the post and add a code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing code this is just a guess but the childCLickListener may be consuming the event so its not reaching the edit text, try returning false in childClickListener

**Edit**

Okay I just created a small project with your code and I couldn't get the onCildClickListener to fire, changing it to a TextView and it works fine. Its something to do with the EditText (perhaps its consuming the event or its not registering as a click but as a change in focus but I'm just guessing at this point).

So in answer to your question, is it possible - I don't think so. But I did make a small workaround that may be of use.

Attach an `onTouchListener()` to the EditText and check for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

Comment: i try that but it did not work...i have edited my question and add a code for it...

Comment: @triggs : i also have the same scenario .. i have multiple(3-4 textviews on one child) textviews as child.. i want to get the text of the textview.. how can this be done ..please help

Answer (score 3):

what is happening over here is your edittext is taking the focus. So the onChildClick is not getting fired.Try to make editText focus property to false through code.If you do it in .xml file it still wont work.Hopefully it works for you.:)

Comment: This. So hard.  I tried everything recommended on the subject, but no one mentioned this; setting it in the layout XMLs seemed like such a good idea...

Answer (score 3):

Have got the same problem (OnChildClickListener doesn't handle click event). In order to handle child items clicks, make sure your ExpandableListAdapter returns "true" (it "fales" by default) in isChildSelectable:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter  {
```

...

```
@Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        **return true;**
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same prob...N referring to the above answers i coded...here's what i found...

- Make sure SimplerExpandableListAdapters extends BaseExpandableListAdapter and  implements OnChildClickListener.
- Add onchildclick as customExpandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new MyCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, )).
  **"argument" is what u receive in the SimplerExpandableListAdapter class.
  **"MyCustomAdapter" should be replaced with your ExpandableListAdapter(SimplerExpandableListAdapter in ur case)

I'm jus adding a code snippet for reference...

```
    public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements OnChildClickListener {
      private LayoutInflater inflater;
      private ArrayList<Parent> mParent;
```

And add the onchildclick inside the Adapterclass. As shown

```
    public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements OnChildClickListener {
      private LayoutInflater inflater;
      private ArrayList<Parent> mParent;
      public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Parent> parent) {
        mParent = parent;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, int arg3, long arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("trial", "ExpandableList= "+arg0+" ,View= "+arg1+" ,arg2= "+arg2+", arg3= "+arg3+", arg4= "+arg4);
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Add call the the onChildclickListener in the activity where the Expandableview is coded.(MainActivity class in my example).

```
    mExpandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new MyCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayParents));
```

Answer (score 0):

Late Answer, but maybe it helps others. I had the same Problem and to set the ExpandableListView to onItemClickListener() or onItemLongClickListener() does it:

```
    mExpandListView
            .setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //do Your Code here

                    return true;
                }

            });
```